# Splitting Beatifulsoup4's findAll() of HTML into list of lines in Python

Tags: python, html, if-statement, python-3.x, web-crawler

I've only just begun learning Python, as there is a project I had in mind which I *suspected* would be possible using a method of web-crawling through Python.

I have been using a tutorial series, and I am aware that `findAll()` appears to be looked down upon for being primitive (I'm unsure why, and I'll gladly learn any better alternatives, however simple at the same time - I started Python yesterday).

Right now, I have an extremely simply project that simply visits the specified website and grabs the code. However, I want to implement an `if` statement - to find if a certain line is present.

(Where using `soup.findAll('a', {'href': '/login'})` and `soup = Beautifulsoup(requests.get(url).text)`) - All my attempts, trying things like: `if '/login' in soup`  have failed, and I am not sure how to implement an `if` statement to find a single word, or line, in this HTML that was found.

If you are aware of any simpler methods to use here I'd be grateful, however the solution that I identified would be to have the HTML split into lines and/or in an array, and I could use `if <the entire line> in soup:`.

Comment: can you share the url? Also there is nothing wrong with findall, where did you read that?

Answer (score -1):

I think what you want is

`if soup.findAll('a', {'href': '/login'}):...`

findAll returns an empty list (`[]`) if the element isn't found, and Python evaluates empty lists as false in if-statements.

For example, here is a trivial example:

```
>>> soup = bs('<html></html>')
>>> assert soup.findAll('html')
>>> assert soup.findAll('login')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AssertionError
```